# Ayuda con consulta Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas una Ventas,  y Otra Abonos_venta, se guardan las ventas de los clientes con su valor total y todo es a crédito en el día se le pueden hacer varias ventas a un cliente como puede que ninguna, el cliente puede abonar al saldo total que tenga varias veces en el día como puede que no.

Con los siguientes campos un poco resumidos

```
TABLA VENTAS
Fecha
Cliente
Valor_Total

TABLA ABONOS_VENTA
Fecha
Cliente
Valor_debe
Valor_Abono
Nuevo_Saldo
```

Lo que quiero hacer es una consulta que me traiga los agrupado por día el valor total de la venta realizada al cliente y el valor total que abono en el día, como decía puede que compre algo o no, o puede que abone a la deuda ese día o no.

Quiero traer esos datos en una sola fila agrupada por dia en un rango de fechas

Que salga así

```
FECHA | CLIENTE | VALOR_VENTA | VALOR_ABONADO
10-10-2017  ANDRES  $10.000       $5.000   
11-10-2017  ANDRES  $0                 $5.000   
12-10-2017  ANDRES  $100.000     $0   
13-10-2017  ANDRES  $0                  $50.000   
14-10-2017  ANDRES  $10.000        $5.000
```

algo así es lo que quiero hacer, pero no doy como, me bloqueé en que puede que en una tabla haya registros de ese día y en la otra no y viceversa. Los campos de las tablas no son solo esos, solo trato de ilustrar un poco para no enredar mas el problema que tengo, les agradezco dejen consultas que crean pueden ayudarme

Consulta con mas campos y otras tablas, lo anterior es una illustracion

```
SELECT V.`CONSECUTIVO`,
V.`FECHA`,
V.`SEMANA`,
V.`SEMANAINICIO`,
V.`SEMANAFIN`,
V.`TIPODCTOCLIENTE`,
V.`DOCUMENTOCLIENTE`,
'----' AS 'DEBIA',
'----' AS 'ABONO',
V.`CANTIDADPOLLO`,
V.`UNIDADPESO`,
V.`PESOPOLLO`,
V.`VALORUNITARIOPOLLO`,
V.`VALORTOTAL`,
'----' AS 'DEBE',
'----' AS 'AFAVOR',
V.`CLIENTE` ,
'----' AS 'COBRADOR',
'----' AS 'VALOR_A_FAVOR',
'----' AS 'VALOR_DEBE'
FROM `vsventasclientegranjasemana` V WHERE V.`FECHA`>=_FECHAINI AND 
V.`FECHA`<=_FECHAFIN 

UNION

SELECT 
V.`ID` AS CONSECUTIVO,
V.`FECHA`,
week(V.`FECHA`,1) AS `SEMANA`,
(V.`FECHA` - interval (dayofweek(V.`FECHA`) - 1) day) AS `SEMANAINICIO`,
(V.`FECHA` + interval (7 - dayofweek(V.`FECHA`)) day) AS `SEMANAFIN`,
V.`TIPODCTOCLIENTE`,
V.`DOCUMENTOCLIENTE`,
V.`DEBIA`,
V.`ABONO`,
'----' AS 'CANTIDADPOLLO',
'----' AS 'UNIDADPESO',
'----' AS 'PESOPOLLO',
'----' AS 'VALORUNITARIOPOLLO',
'----' AS 'VALORTOTAL',
V.DEBE,
V.`AFAVOR`,
P.`NOMBRE` AS CLIENTE,
PC.`NOMBRE` AS COBRADOR,
vs.VALOR_A_FAVOR,
vs.VALOR_DEBE
FROM `venta_cliente_saldo_abono` V
INNER JOIN `venta_cliente_saldo` VS ON V.`CORRESPONDE`=VS.`CORRESPONDE` AND                 V.`TIPODCTOCLIENTE`=VS.`TIPODCTOCLIENTE` AND V.`DOCUMENTOCLIENTE`=VS.`DOCUMENTOCLIENTE`
    INNER JOIN `persona` P ON V.`TIPODCTOCLIENTE`=P.`TIPODCTO` AND V.`DOCUMENTOCLIENTE`=P.`DOCUMENTO`
    INNER JOIN `persona` PC ON V.`TIPODCTOCOBRADOR`=PC.`TIPODCTO` AND V.`DOCUMENTOCOBRADOR`=PC.`DOCUMENTO`
    WHERE V.`FECHA`>=_FECHAINI AND 
    V.`FECHA`<=_FECHAFIN 
    AND V.CORRESPONDE='1'

    ;
```

Comment: Podrías compartir los intentos que has hecho, que selects has intentados

Comment: Que tal amigo.
ya la edité, agradezco le des un vistazo a la consulta.

Answer (score -1):

¡Ey, que tal Amigo!

Según lo que entendí, puedes hacer eso mediante una **consulta con Join**, la más acertada seria **Inner Join**, en internet hay muchos tutoriales y explicaciones de ello para que lo entiendas.

También para traer todo por un rango de fechas utiliza la sentencia **BETWEEN**, y nuevamente te digo lo mismo con esta parte, en internet hay muchas explicaciones sobre ello.

Acá te dejo un ejemplo, http://www.forosdelweb.com/f21/rango-fechas-con-between-inner-join-1045260/ pero para que lo entiendas mejor te aconsejo que leas antes sobre todo lo que te dije.

¡Espero te sirva, salu2!